# Executing external programs via php in linux server

Tags: php, c++, linux, command-line, executable

I'm trying to use a C++ executable program via Php command line by my Linux web server.

I've done it successfully in windows server by this code :

```
<?php
echo "<hr>";
system("ConsoleApplication.exe");
echo"<hr>";
?>
```

and all outputs by the external program  appears on the page but in the Linux server I tried

```
system("ConsoleApplication.exe");
system("./ConsoleApplication.exe");
exec(), passthru() and .......
```

but none of them works, what am I doing wrong ?
thanks

Comment: Why would you need to allow someone to start an application from the web?

Comment: Not an answer because these are just hints, It's probably alright, but not evidently from your question. I guess it is your own application, so it is a bit a strange hint but normally in unix systems (or nearly all systems except windows) executables don't end with '.exe'.  So even if you named it yourself, it seems strange.  More generally: check your execute-path, check whether you can actually run the executable from the commandline and try with a running a command like `ls`.

Comment: the Linux compiled version dosent ends with .exe  I  just typed .exe in my question to show its a executable file .

Comment: Try put in the full path, eg `system("/home/opt/app/bin/ConsoleApplication.exe");` (or whatever the path may be).

Comment: I tried this too but still not working.